# Adding key value pair into a JSON object dynamically and accessing the updated object in javascript/Node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

The scenario is there will be three javascript files named js_file1.js , js_file2.js and js_file3.js. 
I need to declare a JSON object in js_file1.js like the below one :

```
let configObject = {
key1:"Value1",
key2:"Value2"
};
```

now I am exporting it by:

```
  module.exports={
configObject:configObject
};
```

now I am using it in js_file2.js by `js_fileObject1.configObject` and adding one more key value pair to it like:

```
js_fileObject1.configObject.key3 = "value3";
```

now I need to access this updated object into `js_file3.js`. 
any suggestions to achieve this ? I am losing the last key value pair in js_file3.js and only the original one is coming.

Comment: Maybe `js_file3.js` is running before #2?

Comment: you can write to file or store in global namespace.